# Read/write a latest generation USB Magnetic Stripe Reader using c# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I just bought a new Magnetic Stripe Reader (MSR-609) that I need to write a c# program to read the data off the gift cards swiped from it. The software that comes with the device is buggy and doesn't quite fit what I want. I've been searching for a whole week for a simple example (but complete) on how to do that but the more I read, the more I got confused. I am not sure if I want to look for help on a USB device? an HID device? or a USB-HID device? I find it very disturbing that .NET 4.5 doesn't have anything standard for this.

All I know is the device I have is a new generation MSR and doesn't require any specific USB driver or reading from a Com port. I'll be honest that I'm not very familiar with this topic at all. I downloaded quite a few of c# pre-built projects and tried to run them but all of them are difficult to understand and try to cover or "report" on too many devices. All I need is something as simple as to open the MSR device like a file, read and write to it. That's all. I know how to dissect the data once I get it but the problem is how to get it in.

I know there are a lot of experts out there and this might be a very simple thing for them to do but it is a very difficult topic for me. Please help!!!! and thanks.

Comment: Did the device come with any API documentation at all?  Does it appear in the OS has a USB device?

Comment: No, the device was shipped directly from China with no API except for the buggy software to use it on a tiny CD.  However, I did the research on the web and it seems that many places sell it including Amazon, NewEgg etc. and it DOES work. Except finding technical info about it is difficult. It does appear as a USB device and I am able to get the Vendor ID and Product ID of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a USB HID device try looking at the [Simple HID Library](http://simplehidlibrary.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.  It will give you a start.

But be warned what you want to undertake is *not* as simple as opening a file and read/writing.  You will have to create an interface to the device using P/Invoke and possibly unmanaged code.

Another useful resource is [HID Page](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm).

Comment: Thank you. I actually downloaded that project last night and started playing with it but it seems like it's just got started and still an on-going project. Again, that says that the goal of the project is way more than what I need and thus may ask a lot of complexity into it which makes digesting it more difficult for my limited knowledge on this topic. I'll keep you posted on what I find.

Comment: It should be enough to show how to use the VID and PID to start talking to the device though?

Comment: Yes, I was able to see and connect to the device. Just a matter of figure out how to read/write it. BTW, I contacted the seller and he pointed to a website to download the SDK. I did that and got an SDK written in Borland C++. I left C++ quite sometimes ago so I'm trying to convert it to C#. I never realized that programming an MSR is this much complex. On a different note, I did more research and ordered a MagTek  MSR that can emulate keyboard inputs. I have not got the unit but it seems that reading such a device is much easier than writing native code to talk to the device.

Comment: I wanted to give an update. I got the MagTek and I could swipe and read a card in no time. So for those who run into the same problem like me and wanted to get the data in quick, this option seems to be the best. The catch is you have to have the focus for the text box before you swipe the card. Just think about it like instead of manually type in the text, the magnetic stripe reader just helps to get it in much faster without a chance for error. I couldn't make the text box hidden because I used the "AutoCallBack" and "OnTextChanged" to get the data.